# What is regressive about a regression line?

Tags: regression, terminology

I know what a regression line is.

What I'm curious about is the use of the word "regression".  What's regressive about a regression line?

The etymology of ["regression"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=regression) is

> early 15c., from Latin regressionem (nominative regressio) "a going back, a return," noun of action from past participle stem of regredi).

So, how is a regression line a "going back, a return"?

Comment: I believe the origin of the term is from the idea of "regression to the mean."  If I remember correctly the first usage was by Sir Francis Galton and the term simply stuck: http://galton.org/essays/1880-1889/galton-1886-jaigi-regression-stature.pdf